# how to read connection string from another project appsettings file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

**Project Explaination:**

I'm new to ASP NET CORE. **Using DB First** I have three project in my solution. Which are.

> User.API (web api project)
>
> User.Data (c# class library having database methods and db insatace)
>
> User.Model (c# class library having scaffolding db context and
> generated model classes)

The request flow is like, Api sends a call to GetUser() Method in `Data project` then Data project uses Db Context intance and retrieves data.

**Problem:**
In context file I have

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
              optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=UserDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }
```

I want to use a named connection instead of the hard coded connection string like below

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=UserCloudConnectionString");
```

I tried different solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243885/appsettings-json-file-not-in-net-core-console-project) but could not get it. Which project I have to add a file and where I need add json file in `startup.cs` file

**Any Help would be much Appreciated.**

Comment: *Don't* configure the connection string in `OnConfiguring`. Do it in the `AddDbContext` call where you register the DbContext. At that point you have access to `Configuration` and can call`Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")` to get the connection string. `appsettings` isn't a special file, it's just a default name for a JSON file containing settings. Such settings, including connection strings, can come from environment variables, command-line arguments or other sources. To read them, you need access to the configuration middleware, eg through `IConfiguration`

Comment: OnConfiguring is a generated method in Context file. When I used scaffold command to get tables from database. it was generated like this.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean you need to use it. There's no way to read connection strings by name from *inside* a DbContext. Those settings are available through the Configuration middleware. DbContext isn't tied to that middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't configure the connection string in `OnConfiguring`. Do it in the `AddDbContext` call where you register the DbContext. At that point you have access to `Configuration` and can call`Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")` to get the connection string.

```
services.AddDbContext(optionsBuilder=>
{
    var cns=Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserCloudConnectionString");
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(cns);
}
```

`appsettings` isn't a special file, the way `web.config` was. It's just a default name for a JSON file containing settings. Such settings, including connection strings, can come from environment variables, command-line arguments or other sources. To read them, you need access to the configuration middleware, eg through `IConfiguration`.

The `DbContext` class isn't hard-wired to use the Configuration, or any other middleware, so it can't read connection strings by name. It *is* built to handle external configuration though. In the generated code, `!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured` checks whether the DbContext was already configured, eg by `AddDbContext` :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Even if you don't use Dependency Injection, you can create and pass the connection settings through the [DbContext(DbContextOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.-ctor?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext__ctor_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptions_) constructor. [DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions?view=efcore-5.0) is an abstract class, so you need to use a [DbContextOptionsBuilder< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder-1?view=efcore-5.0) to create it:

```
var cns=... //Get the connection string from somewhere
var optionsBuilder=new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
var options=optionsBuilder
                 .UseSqlServer(cns)
                 .Options;

using var ctx=new MyDbContext(options);
```

Comment: AGAIN, it took me a while to understand what you said. I had to add `var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserContext>();` to make it work. Thanks again that was so helpful